# sudo update-grub /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'

Tags: grub2, persistence

when I execute the following command a error message appears:

```
sudo update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'
```

I am using my ubuntu in a persitent usb mode.

How I could fix this error?

I just want to modify the file **/etc/default/grub**, in particular the following line

**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""**

Comment: Hi. What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*persitent usb mode*" means you are using a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment, not an *installed* version of Ubuntu.

The bootloader (GRUB) on a LiveUSB is read-only, even with persistence enabled.

GRUB loads even before the kernel, and well before the filesystems are mounted. Writable files on a persistent LiveUSB can be only in one of those later-mounted filesystems. They are useless for GRUB changes -- they load too late. To make changes to GRUB, you would need to remake the entire LiveUSB image, which is not easy.

It would be much simpler to use an *installed* release of Ubuntu on a USB stick. That GRUB would be writable.

Comment: You are right!!!!. Thank you!!